# When does 'FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed' occur?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I get FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed if I go to sign in, it redirects to the browser, but then I home out of the browser and back to my app (hence skipping the login process in the browser and essentially cancelling login).

What other situations does it occur? Is it only 'user cancelled' situations?

Comment: It happens any time login fails. This includes server-side errors, if your app is misconfigured, if the user canceled login, etc.

Comment: Is there any way of knowing whether the user cancelled the operation as opposed to some error?

Comment: Have a look in FBError.h, the NSError you get in the callback should contain a reason, and it could be FBErrorLoginFailedReasonUserCancelledValue, FBErrorLoginFailedReasonUserCancelledSystemValue, FBErrorLoginFailedReasonInlineCancelledValue, etc.